# Inline Style not applying to asp:checkbox?

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

Inline Style is not applying in the asp:checkbox, instead it applies to span?

```
<td style="width: 100px; height: 25px">
<asp:CheckBox ID="Test" Text="Testing" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"></asp:CheckBox>
</td>
```

The css applies to span and not to that checkbox specifically. If I debug the browser and apply it there, it takes effect.

Comment: I found that I can use InputAttributes.CssStyle but it has to be behind the code. Is there a way to use it in the mark up?

Answer (score 0):

If you realy want to use code inside markup , you can use the html input  :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Test1" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" />
```